# I'm trying to graph a rational function in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I'm attempting to graph the function y=[(x-2)(x+2)]/[(x-3)(x+3)].  However, I get bizarre output, which consists of straight lines.  Any idea what's wrong?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[gray,very thin] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);

\draw[black, very thick,<->](-5,0) -- (5,0);

\draw[black,very thick,<->](0,-5) -- (0,5);

\draw[very thick,domain=-5:-3.20156] plot ({\x},{((\x-2)(\x+2))/((\x-3)(\x+3))});

\draw[very thick,domain=-2.8577:2.8577] plot ({\x},{((\x-2)(\x+2))/((\x-3)(\x+3))});

\draw[very thick,domain=3.20156:5] plot ({\x},{((\x-2)(\x+2))/((\x-3)(\x+3))});

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You get what you ask for, I think. What fixes the domains you're using?

Comment: The domain is determined by the bounds -5<y<5.

Comment: Yes, but you also forgot the multiplication signs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply forgot multiplication signs and can make your life much more comfortable if you use `declare function`. And even even simpler with pgfplots because then you can just "jump" over singularities.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=((\x-2)*(\x+2))/((\x-3)*(\x+3));},
samples=101]
 \draw[gray,very thin] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
 \draw[black, very thick,<->](-5,0) -- (5,0);
 \draw[black,very thick,<->](0,-5) -- (0,5);
 \draw[very thick,domain=-5:-3.20156] plot ({\x},{f(\x)});
 \draw[very thick,domain=-2.8577:2.8577] plot ({\x},{f(\x)});
 \draw[very thick,domain=3.20156:5] plot ({\x},{f(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=((\x-2)*(\x+2))/((\x-3)*(\x+3));}]
 \begin{axis}[grid=major,axis lines=middle,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
 unbounded coords=jump,samples=101]
  \addplot[domain=-5:5] {f(x)};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none,arrowscale=1.5]{<->}(0,0)(-5,-5)(5,5)
\psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=501,yMaxValue=5.5,
  linewidth=1.5pt]{-5}{5}{(x-2)*(x+2)/((x-3)*(x+3))}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]